# Check character from input count occurance in String

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to count the occurrence of a single digit to that in a string.
What I mean by this is The user types in a sentence in a multi line `TextBox` and below in a separate text field a single letter. I need to check how many times that single letter occurs in the sentence.

Currently, I have the input of the two text fields by using this

```
string InputSingleline = SingleLineTxtBox.Text;
string InputMultiline = MultiLineTxtBox.Text;
```

And I'm trying to count the occurance of input in `InputSingleLine` in `MultiLineTxtBox` by using this but it does not work.

```
int Count = InputMultiline.Count(f => f == SingleLineTxtBox);
```

Comment: @S.Akbari There you go: https://imgur.com/a/LQhsz

Comment: Firstly, you're not trying to count the occurrences of `InputSingleLine` - you're trying to count the occurrences of `SingleLineTxtBox`, which makes no sense. Next, you should try to count the occurrences of a *character*, not a *string* - so you want something like `char characterToFind = SingleLineTxtBox.Text[0];` (after checking that there *is* actually a single character there). Then you can use `int count = InputMultiLine.Count(f => f == characterToFind);`. As an aside, I'd strongly recommend learning about C# naming conventions as early as possible to avoid getting into bad habits.

Comment: @JonSkeet But what if `SingleLineTxtBox` is empty?  Using `char characterToFind = SingleLineTxtBox.Text[0];` will throw `Index was outside the bounds of the array.'`

Comment: @S.Akbari: Hence the "after checking that there is actually a single character there" part of my comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right. I didn't noticed this part of your comment inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should count the occurrences of `InputSingleline` instead of  `SingleLineTxtBox` since you have already set the `InputSingleline` to `SingleLineTxtBox.Text`. And secondly the `InputSingleline` is a string with one character, so you need to use something like [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) to return that character from this string:

```
int Count = InputMultiline.Count(f => f == InputSingleline.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Using `FirstOrDefault` means it'll look for U+0000 if the text box is empty. Surely it would be better just to detect that and not look.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sentence = "You might be surprised to learn that";
char singleChar = 'i';
int count = sentence.Count(f => f == singleChar);
```

PS: Only in .NET 3.5

Answer (score -1):

```
string pattern = string.Format("^{0}$", InputSingleline);
int count = Regex.Matches(InputMultiline, pattern).Count;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's probably better to include more context/explanation. (I didn't downvote BTW).